# Allow duplicate of stored id in session to be inserted in database

Tags: php, mysql, database, session, duplicates

In database I already have this inside:

```
id | username  | password
=========================
3  |   John    |  happy
```

The same user register an account whose id of 3 is stored in PHP session. I want to store another row where the id is also 3 into the database.

The output will be something like this:

```
id | username  | password
=========================
3  |   John    |  happy
3  |   Emily   |   sad
```

So far I got this:

abc.php

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM account WHERE username='".$username."' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
    $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'] ;
}

<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['id'];?>">
```

cba.php

```
$id = $_POST['custom'];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO user (id, username, password) VALUES('".$id."', '".$username."', '".$password."')") or die(mysql_error());
```

I tried with the session where the id is 3 and try to insert into the database but nothing is inserted.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: Why would you allow the same ID to be used? Looks bad in a security sense as different users can potentially have access to someone else's session.

Answer (score 0):

Very curious why you want to do this. Any who, you could try something like:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO user (id, username, password)
SELECT MAX(id), '" . $username . "', '" . $password . "' FROM user";
```

Hope you're also not storing the password in plain text.

Comment: I'm using this for testing purpose. Nope, will not store those password as plain text as well.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is have "two unique" values that are the same. It can't be done. Else the values aren't unique anymore.

To answer you question, if the field you want to store the value in is not a field where you enforce uniqueness, then a simple insert should do it. Unless you want to fetch values from the database and make duplicates. It's hard to make out what you want. But just trying to insert a value you know is already in the field. It will work if it's not a unique or a primary field.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need an update query. As the id is already present(user is registered as he session has an id), you need to update the existing user's info with new details.